# implementation of shift reduce parser in java

Tags: java

i need to implement the shift reduce parser in my college ,i need to know how can i implement it using java
is there is any implementations already .... or any sample one

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Isn't the algo already explained in your college book? Otherwise Wiki is also helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing#An_example_of_shift-reduce_parsing

Comment: guys i am interested in writing but i struck in the piratical logic implementation can any one explain practically not theoretically

Comment: Is this question different than this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055220/an-example-implementation-of-shift-reduce-parsing

Answer (score 3):

> **is there any implementations already?**

Unless the task is to actually practice writing it yourself, I'd recommend using a parser generator such as [JavaCUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). (I used JavaCUP in one of my compiler courses, but perhaps you have a different scope in your course.)